# Common vertex to two relationships in OrientDb

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

I am trying to pick up OrientDb and am trying out a few test queries to get a feel for the syntax and power of using graph databases. In particular I am having difficulty in find a common vertex satisfying two independent relationships to two other vertices that are unrelated.

For example,

Assuming I have a person vertex having attribute name, a car vertex having a model and a location vertex with attribute zip with the following edge dependencies

Person --- owns --> Car

Person --- lives --> Location

I am trying to find all the Person vertices that own a particular model of car and live at a particular zip.

I am not sure exactly what I am missing in my efforts, but any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume this domain model:

```
Car <--- Owns ---|   Person   |--- Lives ---> Location
*   <--- Owns ---|1          *|--- Lives ---> 1
```

All the persons who own a particular car model:

```sql
select expand(in('Owns')) from Car where model = 'Volvo'
```

All the persons who live at a particular zip:

```sql
select expand(in('Lives')) from Location where zip = '10770'
```

Let's combine the above to get all the persons who own a particular car model and live at a particular zip:

```sql
select from (
    select expand(in('Owns')) from Car where model = 'Volvo'
) where out('Lives') contains (zip='10770')
```

Minor:

- The function `expand()` transforms the result set so as you get more than just the record IDs in the print out.
- Passing `Owns`/`Lives` to the `in`/`out` functions ensures that only the edges of class types `Owns`/`Lives` are traversed.

Comment: Thank you. This is very useful. I was unaware of the out being used independent of the expand() transform as you did with the where part of the query.